# Why are grid items overflowing the grid container?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want my grid container to auto-adjust to the content it has. It's parent also has a height of auto. At this time, the grid is being overflowed by its content.
It has this behavior:

```
xxxxxxxxxxcontainerxxxxxxxxxx   _
|         |        |        |    |
|         |        |        |    |
|_________|________|________|    |
|         |        |        |    |
|         |        |        |    |
|_________|________|________|    |---------Grid items
|         |        |        |    |
|         |        |        |    |
|_________|________|________|    |
|xxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxx|    | 
|         |        |        |    |
|_________|________|________|   _|
```

I've tried to use the grid-template-columns, but it was only affecting the first row, so tried using grid-auto-columns and it resizes all the rows, but still overflowing.

I expect that if I add another row, the grid container will be resized to its content.

```css
#allyes {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-image: url('../img/fondo-laptop.webp');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#allyes #allyesLogos {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

#allyes #allyesTitle {
  font-size: var(--bigTitleSize);
  font-family: var(--titleFamily);
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#allyesLogos .logosTable {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: grid;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-gap: 2% 3%;
}
```

```html
<section id="allyes">
  <div id="allyesLogos">
    <h1 id="allyesTitle">alianzas comericales</h1>
    <div class="logosTable">
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/4yousee.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/benq.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/bright-sign.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/dell.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/dynascan.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/elo.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/fortinet.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/glassapps.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/hisense.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/iadea.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/lenovo.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/LG.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/nec.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/panasonic.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/samsung.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/screengoo.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="<?php echo $httpProtocol.$host.$url.'img/logos-alianzas/sharp.webp'?>" alt="ally"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: not too sure i understand, but your rows are set to 70px. is this what you wanted or did you expect them to shrink/expand somehow ?

Comment: I'd like to shrink/expand my rows with a minimum height of 70px, but when I used the grid-template-rows it only affected to the first row. But I have no problem if is not possible and is necesary to have the item with a fixed height to achieve the grid container to auto size to it's content.

Comment: okay, is `grid-auto-rows: minmax(70px,auto);` a better option sizing your rows ?

Comment: It helps, thank you for that :D. But the main problem stills and the grid container gets overflowed by its content.

Comment: i see , your cells will not grow past the 180px you set, i do not see anyvworkaround for this behavior , beside an overflow on the cell itself `.allyLogo { max-width:100%; overflow:auto;}` . grid, flex, table, float, ... none are perfect unfortunately :(

Comment: I just adjusted de margin of the .logosTable so it resizes the #allyesLogos to fit the content, it is not the optimum to do, but i works. I hope there still an optimum answer to this behavior  :D

Comment: yes , that might help too, for bigger content, you might also consider spanning through rows or columns or both if you have any clue in advance that this or that cell is much bigger than others or sizing set. javascript could also help on the fly. Maybe the masonry script/behavoir is what you expect from your layout ;)

Comment: Oh, thank you, it had not occurred to me, but I think I need to read a little more about what you mention, so I can use it correctly. If it's not too much to ask, do you think you can provide me with an article that talks about it?

Comment: about spanning through, a reminder/tutorial about grid :  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ should remind/tell you how this works, for the javascript part , it's up to you or your devellopper to set when this or this action has to be made on your  CSS template

Comment: i really recommend you to use some kind of template system like smarty or twig. Coding like this is so horrorable :D

Comment: @G-Cyr I have readed that page you suggested and I remembered that when I entered into the flex and grid world I read the one you sended for grid and the one for the flex. One other page that I use as a refference to grid layout is [link](https://gridbyexample.com/)

Comment: @Dwza I'd like to use some template, but I really need to learn to use all the handdy part

Comment: @maneroto guess your first step should be, choose a framework to use. Working with an "from the scratch" attitude is deprecated :) And for sure, every tutorial for an framwark runs through some template system. I e.g. prefer symfony. Whats quite nice, helps you a lot and easy to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the source of the problem:

```
grid-gap: 2% 3%
```

It appears that the **percentage** grid gaps are being factored into the layout **after** the rendering engine has set the dimensions of the container.

It may also be an issue with *what the percentages are being based on* (container height? row height? something else?).

Either way, percentage values for grid gaps are causing grid items to overflow the grid container.

Try using a different unit of length, such as `vh`, `px` or `em`. They seem to work fine.

In the demo below, I used `grid-gap: 2vh 3vh`.

```css
#allyes {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-image: url('../img/fondo-laptop.webp');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#allyes #allyesLogos {
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

#allyes #allyesTitle {
  font-size: var(--bigTitleSize);
  font-family: var(--titleFamily);
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#allyesLogos .logosTable {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: grid;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  /* grid-gap: 2% 3%; */
    grid-gap: 2vh 3vh; /* adjustment */
  border: 1px solid red; /* demo */
}
```

```html
<section id="allyes">
  <div id="allyesLogos">
    <h1 id="allyesTitle">alianzas comericales</h1>
    <div class="logosTable">
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
      <div class='allyLogo'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

*Also note: The problem described in the question exists in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Edge. The grid container in Edge expands naturally to accommodate grid items along with percentage grid gaps.*

Comment: not too sure (again :) ) , but i think problem occurs once the grid cell is over the 180px/70px size set in the CSS grid set. , note , i do not have edge aside to run and test anything that would be bigger than the 180/70 px size.

Comment: @G-Cyr, possibly. Maybe I have misunderstood the question. I'll wait for feedback from the OP. Thank you.

Comment: okay, i'm filling about the same. the op seems to handle quiet well the grid model. .. and my english is just average.. I think a working snippet showing clearly the issue  is needed at this point :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved the problem, I forgot that grid-gap had all that power to affect my entire grid in that way. But also, It helped me a lot to see that minmax that G-Cyr suggested. Thank you both. Cheers.